# Neural net giving wrong and varying answers even with a high accuracy

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning

I wrote a net for the notMNIST dataset which contains grayscale 28*28 alphabets from A-J.

the model is giving an accuracy of 89% on the test dataset, however when I check the result for an individual image from the train dataset (not even talking about a custom image) it gives wrong results, and also, if I run the same block of code again and again, the results vary for the single output.

I must be doing something really wrong here, but I'm just starting out with deep learning.

## My model ->

```
batch_size = 128
#tensorflow datasets
tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, image_size*image_size))
tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)
#weights and biases for layer 1
weights_l1 = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal([image_size*image_size, 1024])
)
biases_l1 = tf.Variable(
    tf.zeros([1024])
)
#output layer weights and biases
weights = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal([1024, num_labels])
)
biases = tf.Variable(
    tf.zeros([num_labels])
)

hl1 = tf.matmul(tf_train_dataset, weights_l1) + biases_l1
hl1 = tf.nn.relu(hl1)

logits = tf.matmul(hl1, weights) + biases

loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf_train_labels, logits=logits)
)


optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(loss)

#validation predictions
v_hl1 = tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset, weights_l1) + biases_l1
v_hl1 = tf.nn.relu(v_hl1)
v_logits = tf.matmul(v_hl1, weights) + biases
#test predictions
t_hl1 = tf.matmul(tf_test_dataset, weights_l1) + biases_l1
t_hl1 = tf.nn.relu(t_hl1)
t_logits = tf.matmul(t_hl1, weights) + biases

train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(v_logits)
test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(t_logits)
```

## Training step->

```
num_steps = 3001

with tf.Session() as session:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    for step in range(num_steps):
        offset = (step*batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0]-batch_size)
        feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset: train_dataset[offset: offset+batch_size, :], 
                     tf_train_labels: train_labels[offset: offset+batch_size, :]
                    }
        _, l, predictions = session.run([optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        if(step%500 == 0):
            print ('minibatch no.', step)
            print ('current loss', l)
            print("Minibatch accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(predictions, train_labels[offset: offset+batch_size, :]))
            print("Validation accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels))
    print("Test accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels))
```

## output->

minibatch no. 0
current loss 351.531
Minibatch accuracy: 7.8%
Validation accuracy: 27.7%
minibatch no. 500
current loss 6.78443
Minibatch accuracy: 82.0%
Validation accuracy: 81.9%
minibatch no. 1000
current loss 6.5816
Minibatch accuracy: 80.5%
Validation accuracy: 81.9%
minibatch no. 1500
current loss 4.70451
Minibatch accuracy: 81.2%
Validation accuracy: 82.4%
minibatch no. 2000
current loss 3.25759
Minibatch accuracy: 84.4%
Validation accuracy: 79.1%
minibatch no. 2500
current loss 4.18851
Minibatch accuracy: 82.8%
Validation accuracy: 81.6%
minibatch no. 3000
current loss 2.84338
Minibatch accuracy: 86.7%
Validation accuracy: 83.0%
Test accuracy: 89.0%

## Testing for an image->

(lets say the image is an 'F')

```
image_file = 'EE.png'
image_data = (ndimage.imread(image_file).astype(float) - 
                    pixel_depth / 2) / pixel_depth
new_image_data = image_data.reshape([1, 784])
new_image_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(new_image_data)
new_image_data = tf.cast(new_image_data, dtype=tf.float32)
answer = tf.matmul(new_image_data, weights_l1) + biases_l1
answer = tf.nn.relu(answer)
answer = tf.matmul(answer, weights) + biases
answer = tf.nn.softmax(answer)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print(sess.run(answer))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code you reinitialize the network to random values and then try to solve for your image input.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print(sess.run(answer))
```

The following code produces the output you want:

```
logits.eval(feed_dict={tf_train_dataset:answer})
```

You can reuse the variables for the calculation on the test and validation sets. You do not have to use new tensors. If you want to use different variables you need to access the same variables. I urge you to do the standard MNIST tutorial provided by the tensorflow homepage to understand the underlying concepts.

If you do not need to understand those concepts I can point you to keras (https://keras.io/) which is a wrapper for tensorflow, which hides aways this complexity.

Comment: Thanks, but I still am unable to run the code. wouldn't feed_dict also require the tf_train_labels to be given some value?

Comment: and also, why are we applying .eval() on the logits? shouldn't it be applied to the train_predictions?

Comment: Because logits describes the learned function. By optimizing the loss obtained by the cross entropy of the logits to the labels the function is learned and by evaluating this function you get the desired output

Comment: actually my train_prediction contained the softmax'd logits, so I had to eval that, but now I got my code working! thanks

Comment: Updated my answer to address another problem in your code.

Comment: Doesnt softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits apply the softmax to the logits?

Comment: Sry do not know where my head was when I wrote that. At least it works now.